# Typecast int variables to strings in Jython for use in Sikuli

Tags: jython, sikuli, sikuli-script

I want define a path using the looping variable like this:

```
for i in range(2,4):
    click("1480530304554.png")
    wait("1480531095180.png")   
    type("cd D:\ISB\Pairs\" + str(i) + "\Acq\" + Key.ENTER)
```

This typecasting does not work in Sikuli which supports jython. Error is:

```
SyntaxError ( "no viable alternative at input 'cq'", )
```

Whats the way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows systems, to define a path you must use double backslash. This will do what you need:

```
type("cd D:\\ISB\\Pairs\\" + str(i) + "\\Acq\\" + Key.ENTER)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use double backslash `\\` or `/` instead of backslash `\`
Single backslash is an escape character